# How can I set $window.variable using webpack?

Tags: angularjs, webpack

I'm migrating a project from a custom builder using Grunt to Webpack and I'm having a problem importing an external library.

This library I have to import is named angular-hu-caches and requires $window.LRUCache to exist (https://github.com/angular-hu/bower-caches/blob/master/caches.js#L414)

I've configured my ProvidePlugin like this but it is not working:

```
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      'UNIAPI.Types': 'uniapi-types',
      'window.UAParser': 'ua-parser',
      'window.LRUCache': 'serialized-lru-cache',
      'LRUCache': 'serialized-lru-cache'
    })
 ],
```

Aliases are configured like this:

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    // ...
    'serialized-lru-cache': 'serialized-lru-cache/lib/lru-cache.js'
  }
}
```

I think the problem is using $window instead of window. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

You should try DefinePlugin, something like this:

```
plugins: [
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'UNIAPI.Types': 'uniapi-types',
    UAParser: 'ua-parser',
    LRUCache: 'serialized-lru-cache'
  })
],
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried @serginator solution but it didn't work fine because the imported library was using $window.LRUCache to refer to LRUCache instead of window.LRUCache.

**I've finally solved this problem using expose-loader**

```
// I require LRUCache once before loading the lib.
require("expose-loader?LRUCache!serialized-lru-cache");

// I use an alias in webpack.config.js
'serialized-lru-cache': 'serialized-lru-cache/lib/lru-cache.js',
```

That code exposes LRUCache as a global object in window and solves the problem.